# Windows compressed folders does not unpack zip completely

Tags: maven-2, windows-xp, zip, maven-assembly-plugin, compressed-folder

I have a big maven project with lots of modules. One of the modules is not 'real' development project. It contains data for the final system. The data is deployed to the system using a special jar. The pom now makes sure that the jar is downloaded and all the other data and batch files are packaged into a zip. It uses the maven assembly plugin. There is no much magic to this pom file. The magic starts when unpacking the zip file with Windows compressed folder. It will only recognize the jar file which is rather big (9MB) and not the batch and data files (a few KB). I didn't notice this right away because my really old Winzip does not have any issues with the artifact.

Does anybody has an idea or has seen similar issues?

---

the plugin configuration from pom file

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

My assembly xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>  

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>com.group:product-development-cli</include>
      </includes>
      <outputFileNameMapping>product-development-cli-${ext.version}.${extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>pom.xml</exclude>
        <exclude>assembly.xml</exclude>
        <exclude>target</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

---

My folder structure:
module
 +- data1
   +- more files
 +- data2
   +- more files
 +- pom.xml
 +- assembly.xml
 +- more files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Edward Thomson, I had another look at the zip file. The zip file contained files from two different sources (fileset and dependency). The issue was the directory tag in the fileSet. (`<directory>.</directory>`) Compressed Folders does not like '.' in the middle of the path.

`product-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT/./file.txt`

The dependency was without the `.` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that you're exceeding the 260 character windows path length limit?  The Windows built-in compression routines fail on it (even when other zip programs can deal with it.)

This seems to crop up frequently when dealing with JARs due to the hierarchical structure of JARs.

Could you try unzipping to a shorter path (`C:\A` for instance) and see if that helps?

Comment: The folders tructure is very flat. However, I tried it anyway with no luck.